# How to Initialize pagination variable

Tags: android, scroll, pagination, progress-bar

I am using one intiger variable.

```
int page=1;

private void pagination() {
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                /*if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                    isScrolling = true;
                }*/
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                currentItems = manager.getChildCount();
                totalItems = manager.getItemCount();
                scrollOutItems = manager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                if (isScrolling) {
                    if (totalItems > previousTotal) {
                        previousTotal = totalItems;
                        page++;
                        isScrolling = false;
                    }
                }
                if (!isScrolling && (currentItems + scrollOutItems == totalItems)) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //page=page+1;
                    /*new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                        }
                    }, 5000);*/
                    getNext();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    isScrolling = true;
                    Log.v("All Courses", "Page Number: " + page);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I want to display all course but using 8 course display and when scroll then next 8 course display. Then i click any course then go to new fragment but i press back button in next fragment for back to course fragment then page variable not initialize 1 value. page variable store next increment value.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code for pagination, it works well. add your **first page data** to yourRecycler **then** set the following **addOnScrollListener**.

```
private Integer currentPage = 1;
yourRecycler.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override 
        void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, Integer newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
            if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                currentPage++;
                getNextPage();
                
            }
        }
    })
```

and you need to add your new page addition actions in following function:

```
private void getCurrentPage(){
    //add new page data to yourRecycler
}
```

note: it was kotlin code, I converted to java. it can has missing semicolons etc.

Comment: I am satisfied this code but I want that when I click recycler view item then go to new fragment then I press mobile back button for go to previous fragment, currentPage variable initialized with again 1 but it store next increment value.